# I am doing my r hw for class and for some reason the p value showing up in the console is different than what is in my knitted document

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I am data science student and I am running into an issue while doing my hw and even my professor can't figure it out.

When I use this code:

```r
associate(Size_of_Party ~ Smoker, data = EX2.TIPS, seed = 9750)
```

I get the following result.

[image: result of associate]

As you can see from above, the p value of ANOVA is between 0.017 and 0.049 which means the test is conclusive.

However, when I knit the document, I get different results for the p value range for the anova test.

[image: result in knitted document]

The p value in my knitted document is showing the p value to be between 0.028 and 0.066 for the ANOVA test which makes sense why it is inconclusive.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I tried to download the latest R studio version, tried to re-run everything and the same thing keeps happening.

Comment: just curious: if you add  set.seed(123) in the same code chunk and knit again, will that solve the problem?

Comment: Knitted documents sometimes cache their results to save time when re-knitting, and this can sometimes lead to issues where data isn't updated when it should. Try disabling cache by adding `r opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)` in the first chunk, and/or try restarting your R environment.

Comment: The first image doesn't show any pvalue.  More generally, you should post complete code so we can evaluate it ourselves; we don't have "associate" or "EX2.TIPS".